# Video tag does not run the video in Jsp

Tags: jsp, html5-video

i am using HTML5 support jsp and i am using the video tag as like

```
<div id="video">
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="/home/works/Desktop/Funny_kids_video_compilation.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</div>
```

But it not working ... how should i want to display my video (ie) not from other sites like youtube etc..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since your code seems to be good, you sure you did not get any error before? maybe is just a permission error /wrong path or whatelse.

Comment: no the path is correct.. i have checked the same by creating the video.html page.. its working fine

Comment: try if this http://www.toly.nl/mmbase/1896/HTML5_jspx_template solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your browser supports the file type for the source video. Different browsers have selective compatibility with different file formats. There is a table of which browsers support which formats here: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_video.asp

Generally it's a good idea to have at least MP4 **AND** webm formats if not ogg too for maximum cross-compatibility.

Good luck!

Comment: i have checked the browser compatibility.. i have created the same as video.html page and checked, its coming... i dono whats the problem while using it in jsp

Answer (score 0):

As it is running in `HTML`, it should run with `JSP` also as after all when JSP pages are served in browser they are converted in `HTML` only.

So, In my opinion Check output generated by `JSP` and find the difference between your running `HTML (i.e. video.html)` and `JSP` code.

Chances of difference are at `src="/home/works/Desktop/Funny_kids_video_compilation.mp4"` in your `video` tag.

This will help in solving problem.